# How to trigger a workflow job in repository B(downstream job) from workflow job of repository A in Github using github actions

Tags: git, github, github-actions

I have a requirement where there are 3 GitHub repositories.
Repo A 
Repo B 
Repo C

The workflow starts when a parameterized job1 of Repo A is executed manually(using workflow_disptach).
 Four parameters are passed.
This job1 triggers two other jobs of Repo B(job2) and Repo C(job3)->(downstream jobs)

After successful execution of the jobs of Repo B & C, job1(shell script) of Repo A with all the 4 parameters should be executed.

how to trigger a job workflow in different repositories? 
How to checkout the code to some different location other than GITHUB_WORKSPACE env?
How to achieve the above use case in Github using Github Actions?

Comment: With the right permissions, you can use the Github Actions API to trigger any workflow from any repository through the [post /repos/{owner}/{repo}/actions/workflows/{workflow_id}/dispatches](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/actions#create-a-workflow-dispatch-event) endpoint.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**How to trigger a job workflow in different repositories?**

As [soltex](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2908330/soltex) said in comments, you can use `dispatches` to trigger a workflow on any repository using the `repository_dispatch` trigger.

[Github API repositories documentation](https://docs.github.com/pt/rest/reference/repos#create-a-repository-dispatch-event)

Here is a workflow example to send a `dispatch event` using the Github API: [triggered](https://github.com/GuillaumeFalourd/poc-github-actions/blob/main/.github/workflows/4-dispatch-event-workflow.yml) - [receiver](https://github.com/GuillaumeFalourd/ritchie-formulas-scheduler-demo/blob/main/.github/workflows/6-formulas-scheduler-remote-dispatch.yml).

**How to achieve the above use case in Github using Github Actions?**

There are some actions on the [Github Marketplace](https://github.com/marketplace?type=actions&query=dispatch) that make it easier to dispatch event.

Here is a workflow example of an action doing it: [triggered](https://github.com/GuillaumeFalourd/useful-actions/blob/main/.github/workflows/repository-dispatch.yml) - [receiver](https://github.com/GuillaumeFalourd/useful-actions/blob/main/.github/workflows/repository-dispatch-triggered.yml)

**How to checkout the code to some different location other than GITHUB_WORKSPACE env?**

If in the same repository, once you used the `actions/checkout` to access the GITHUB_WORKSPACE, you can navigate the repository using shell commands (for example: `cd path/to/specific/file`) to access the folder or file you wish.

Now, if you want to access a specific file or folder from another repository, you'll have to clone it somewhere into your workflow.